# Miktex in Ubuntu 9.10 x86-64

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, latex, miktex

do you know how to install the Miktex Distribution in (K)Ubuntu 9.10 x86-64?

Answer (score 2):

Why? You have very current texlive packages in Debian and Ubuntu. See below for the first 10 of 91 total packages available to you.

```
edd@joe:~$ cat /etc/motd.tail

To access official Ubuntu documentation, please visit:
http://help.ubuntu.com/
edd@joe:~$ apt-cache search texlive- | grep -c "^texlive"
91
edd@joe:~$ apt-cache search texlive- | grep  "^texlive" | head
texlive-base - TeX Live: Essential programs and files
texlive-base-bin - TeX Live: Essential binaries
texlive-base-bin-doc - TeX Live: Documentation files for texlive-base-bin
texlive-bibtex-extra - TeX Live: Extra BibTeX styles
texlive-common - TeX Live: Base component
texlive-doc-base - TeX Live: Base documentation
texlive-doc-bg - TeX Live: Bulgarian documentation
texlive-doc-cs+sk - TeX Live: Czechslovak documentation
texlive-doc-de - TeX Live: German documentation
texlive-doc-el - TeX Live: Greek documentation
edd@joe:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

MikTex is for Windows.
I suggest using TexLive, it's now the most active LaTeX distribution on Unix apparently.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must have MiKTeX and not texlive, you should be able to install it through wine.  Failing that, it will certainly install inside a virtualbox image.